# If $\mathbb{E}(X_n)$ is finite for $n=1,2,...$, are $\mathbb{E}|X_n|$ and $\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|\right)$ also finite?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I'm not sure that I can think of a counter example for the first one. It seems intuitive to me that this is the case, but perhaps there could exist a sequence of random variables whereby mean of the sum of them is 0, but the mean of the sum of their absolute values is infinite. Or am I totally off the ball here?

Comment: Yes and they both follow by definitions.

Answer (score 1):

- $\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|X_i|\right] =\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left[|X_i|\right]$ so is finite iff each of the $\mathbb{E}\left[|X_i|\right]$ is finite
- If $\mathbb{E}\left[|X_i|\right]$ is infinite then $\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]$ is either infinite or undefined, while if $\mathbb{E}\left[|X_i|\right]$ is finite then $\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]$ is finite

So each of the $\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]$ being finite implies that each of the $\mathbb{E}\left[|X_i|\right]$ is finite and that $\mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|X_i|\right]$ is finite